# Confusion as to what this is exactly returning (WinNT in VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

```
'get list of all users on domain

     Dim de As New DirectoryEntry()
     de.Path = "WinNT://Domain.mydomain/JohnDoe2-1"
     For Each d As DirectoryEntry In de.Children()
        Console.WriteLine(d.Name)
        Console.ReadLine()
    Next
```

When I run WintNT://Domain.mydomain it lists the users on the domain.
When I run it with /JOhnDoe2-1 I get a list of something. Are these files and is there a way to expand to search within them?

Any hints toward searching domain users for a specific file would be helpful.
Thanks folks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What that returns depends on what JohnDoe2-1 is... is it a user?  a computer name?  something else?  We don't know...

For hints on solving your problem, look at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772211(v=VS.85).aspx
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746534(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks hopefully this leasds to something.John Doe is the name of a user on the domain.